# Initialize DateTime 01/01/Current year and 31/12/Current year

Tags: php, datetime

I'm struggling with the PHP-DateTime Object.
I just want to set the beginn date to the start of the current year and the end date to the end of the current year.

Is there an easy way to create such a date in one line?

```
$beg = new DateTime();//TO-DO 01.01.ThisYear
$this->beginDate = $beg;
$end = new DateTime();//TO-DO EndOfThisYear
$this->endDate = $end;
```

I'm using an older PHP-Version, don't know exactly which one...something above 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure:

```
$beg = new DateTime(date('Y-01-01'));
$end = new DateTime(date('Y-12-31'));
```

Comment: thx, in the context I was programming this I needed to write it with a backslash like this btw:
`$beg = new \DateTime(date('Y-01-01')); $end = new \DateTime(date('Y-12-31'));`